# After loading extjs data store with data, setting the title of the toolbar doesn't work

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4

I have a button with this handler:

```
handler:function(){
            myapp.functions.createDealerList();
            myapp.mainPanel.setActiveItem(myapp.cards.dealerList, { type: 'slide', direction: 'left'});
            myapp.toolbars.dealerListNav.setTitle("Page 1 of " + myapp.stores.dealerList.data.items[0].data.pageTotal);
            }
```

createDealerList create an extjs list and populates it with my json echoed data (by using the load() property on my data store). I then try to set the title of the toolbar. When I click the button the list is rendered with the loaded data but the title on the toolbar isn't set.

On the the card with this list I have another button next page which updates the list and also sets the title of the toolbar, the code is:

```
myapp.toolbars.dealerListNav.setTitle("Page " +sendpage+ " of " + myapp.stores.dealerList.data.items[0].data.pageTotal);
```

And that works! So I wonder what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: use callback function with load method.